# Using shortcodes for dbquery in wordpress the german quotation marks disapear

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I have a mysql table with a text field containing German text with German quotes. E.g. „Freda“.

If I read the database directly via php the result is correct. But when I generate a shortcode in wordpress that contains the same php query of the database, the german quotes disappear. All other characters are displayed.

For this reason i want to change the german quotation marks in the DBfield to '„' '“'.

With the following command I can replace the quotes with the entity '„' or '“' using phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE `TableName` SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(`fieldname`, '„', '&bdquo;') WHERE `fieldname` LIKE '%„%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

But when I want to do this directly using php, I can't manage it. I can change other characters or words but nothing happens with the quotes. How must the command be formulated in the php file so that I can change it?

I was trying the following codes // as given me from phpmyadmin:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `TableName` SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(`fieldname`, \'„\', \'&bdquo;\') WHERE `fieldname` LIKE \'%„%\' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin";
$sqlRes = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
```

I changed it to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `TableName` SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(`fieldname`, '„', '&bdquo;') WHERE `fieldname` LIKE '%„%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin";
$sqlRes = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
```

I changed it to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE TableName SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, '„', '&bdquo;') WHERE fieldname LIKE '%„%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin";
$sqlRes = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
```

I changed it to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE TableName SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, \'„\', \'&bdquo;\') WHERE fieldname LIKE \'%„%\' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin";
$sqlRes = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
```

But all of this is not working.

Comment: You asked this before in a similar way. Instead of changing the database, let’s work on getting the shortcode working how you want it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have no idea what to change in the shortcode to show the german quotes. That's why I'm trying to change the text in the DBtext field in advance.
Anyway, all german special characters are displayed correctly except the double quotes. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Now I found a solution: If I use mysqli for getting the content of the field, the german quotation marks are lost. Buf if I use WPDB for this, the quotation marks are shown.